# Fourier transform of tanh

Tags: fourier-analysis, hypergeometric-functions

tanh is not absolutely integrable, so a direct fourier transform does not exist. But even for the signum function, which is not absolutely intrgrable, we can get the fourier transform by applying some tricks.

Comment: There is no question here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mathematica says: $$i \sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}} \text{csch}\left(\frac{\pi  t}{2}\right).$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for the information. Can you also tell me the Fourier transform of sigmoid function? Also, what were the Fourier parameters when you took the transform? (I don't have Mathematica with me)

Comment: $\tanh(x)=2S(2x)-1$.